# Change data in list for RecyclerView from a single RecyclerView Item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I want to feed a *list of pairs* to an a *RecyclerView* adapter and update the value of this list based on the selection of an individual RecyclerView item.

Let's say I've got a *list of pairs*, `myList`, which looks like this:

```
 val myList:MutableList <Pair<String, Int>> = mutableListOf(
                   //(Hint, Value)
  Pair<String, Int>("Entry 1", 3), 
  Pair<String, Int>("Entry 2", 5),
  // More entries
  Pair<String, Int>("Entry 4", 0),
)
```

*The *pair* is used to map a hint (or description) of a value to the
value itself. This means, that the first value is just used as the
hint in a *TextInputLayout* and the value itself is set as a
predefined text in a *TextInputEditText* ([Android Developer
Doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout)).*

This list is generated dynamically. So when a fragement is loaded, he user must select a CSV-File and based on the content of the file, the list is generated. This means, the list may change if the user selects a different file.

Now I got my adapter, *adapter*, and my layout for the items (which consist of this *TextInputLayout* and *TextInputEditText*) and use it in my *RecyclerView*.

```java
// The recycler view in my layout
binding.recContent.adapter = adapter
//...
adapter.submitList(myList)
```

For the adapter I'm using a slightly modified version of the [PlantAdapter.kt](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/adapters/PlantAdapter.kt) from the [Google Sunflower Example Project](https://github.com/android/sunflower).

Now, the question is: Is it possible do "link" the items of a *RecyclerView* to immediately update the content in the list `myList`. This means, if the user changes the content of one arbitrary text field, I want to update the corresponding content in my list.
I’ve already come across some other SO-threads, however they are trying to update the content of the adapter from a list, not the content of a list from the user selection of a single RecyclerView-Item (as in my case).

---

Maybe it is a little bit more clear with an image:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, your question is not clear. Can you show use some of the code and indicate where in the code you want to change something and how that change needs to be reflected. You've included a lot of irrelevant information in the question, but not the important bits.

Comment: Okay, I see. However there is not much more code, see [here](https://github.com/android/sunflower/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/sunflower/PlantListFragment.kt)
(1/2)

Comment: I have an adapter-class, which is nearly the same as the one I linked to (just replace the object "Plant" with the Pair). I did not see any advantage to include it, since it would not add any information to my question. The other parts are exactly as given - and there is not "more code" for achieving this. I also can not include " where in the code I want to change something and how that change needs to be reflected" since that exactly what my question is about.  (2/2)

Comment: how does the user "change a value"?

Comment: The fields are, as said Textfields (*TextInputEditText *) that are given a predifined value based on the list. The user "changes" the value of the TextField, as you normally do using textFields. the problem is, that the displayed data and the data of the initial list now diverges. To cope this, I was looking for a way to tell the original list (myList): Hey, your corresponding "Entry 2" has been changed by the user, update the value in your list.
I was hoping that an recyclerView Item is hloding some kind of reference to the list.

Comment: I added more stuff to my answer. Please find some simple basic Android UI tutorials and run through them so that you understand how to perform basic UI functions (like display data and get input data from the user and react to button clicks,etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all of the anser above are not what I was looking for, I've finally found exactly what I wanted to achieve:

*Imo* the most easiest way of doing it is using [ObservableField](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ObservableField)s:

```java
 val myList:MutableList < Pair<String, ObservableField<Int>> > = mutableListOf(
                   //(Hint, Value)
  Pair<String, Int>("Entry 1", ObservableField<Int>(3) ), 
  Pair<String, Int>("Entry 2", ObservableField<Int>(5) ),
  // More entries
  Pair<String, Int>("Entry 4", ObservableField<Int>(0) ),
)
```

The list is submitted to the adapter as you normally do:

```java
// The recycler view in my layout
binding.recContent.adapter = adapter
//...
adapter.submitList(myList)
```

On imporant thing is to *change my databinding* in my xml as well. The `RecyclerView` stays the same similar to:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/llOPConfigFields"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:listitem="@layout/op_content_item">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and the xml for the item `content_item` is now changed, so the databinding using the [two-way data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/two-way) with `android:text="@={value}"` instead of `android:text="@{value}"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="hint"
            type="String"/>
        <variable
            name="value"
            type="String"/>
    </data>
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@{hint.toString()}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/writeContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="@={value}" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</layout>
```

and in the adapter

```
class DatafieldAdapter :
    ListAdapter<DataField, DatafieldAdapter.DatafieldViewHolder>(DatafieldAdapterDiffCallback()) 
{

    //... 
    // some adapter code, see for full code
    // initial question.
    // ...

    class DatafieldViewHolder(private val binding: DatafieldItemBinding) :
            RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root), Observable
    {
            private lateinit var item: Pair<String, ObservableField<Int>>

            init {
                // Add th listener
                binding.writeContent.addTextChangedListener  { it
                    if (it.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
                      // .set updates the value
                      item.Second.set(it.toInt())
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fun bind(item: Pair<String, ObservableField<Int>>) {
            this.item = item // Assign the object
            // do your binding.
        }

        // ...
    }


}
```

Each change using the *TextFields* now immediatly change the value in list.

Answer (score 0):

you can get on top of this quite easily actually. all you need to do is to wrap your data that you feed to your recyclerview in live data. then you can observe the live data for any changes and call your adapter with the new data.

Answer (score 0):

Your adapter has the values (it needs to display them, so it has them), so when the user "changes a value" (however it is he does that), the code should just update the value. You can do this in the adapter directly, but a cleaner way to do this is to propagate this up to whatever `Activity` or `Fragment` or whatever is controlling the whole process. That code can then update the data with the new values and inform the `RecyclerViewAdapter` that the data has changed, using `notifyDatasetChanged()` or `notifyItemChanged()` or one of the other similar methods.

---

To be notified when the user "changes" the value in an `EditText`, add a `TextChangedListener` to the `EditText` field and then implement the methods in the listener. You will be notified when the text changes and you can then get the new data and do womething with it (set it in the item or propagate this up to the `Activity` or `Fragment` for further processing.

NOTE: This is very basic Android UI stuff and I would suggest that you find some simple tutorials about how to create buttons, test fields and input fields on screen and react to the user.

Comment: I don't think that you got my question right. I'm relatively new to Android programming but know use listeners. Since, as you said, this is indeed basic stuff. However, (I guess) the problem is more sophisticated. 
I want to try to achieve this with the approach using recycler views.  Either, my question is formulated too bad (English is not my mother tongue), that someone understand what I want to achieve. Or the approach is usually achieved different und this way of doing it is so far from the usual way, that you again don’t know what I mean. (1/2)

Comment: Nevertheless, I have found a different approach, which I found is not that performant since I'm generating the UI Elements using kotlin code, but works quite well.
But thank you for the discussion and the time you invested. Highly appreciate it. (2/2)

Comment: Well, you can create your own answer and maybe others can learn from that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call adapter.submitList(myList) every time the state of your list changes, passing current myList state. List adapter is using algorithms to compare previous and new state of list, so only objects that had changed will be updated. You can use LiveData class to wrap your list and easily manage variable state, read more about it here:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

Comment: No, this is not the problem. My List is not changed by my application - it should be changable by user. The only way right now is using my items, iterate through all of them, generate a new list and dispose the old one - which I tought is not a very good way of doing it.